# PHP - permanent variable on server accesable by clients

Tags: php, variables, shared-memory

I`m looking for a way to store a data accesable for every client without using a database or a file, something like a variable stored in the server memory.

I want my clients connect to 2 differents servers alternately so this variable will works as a switch, changing between 0 or 1 for each client request.

thank you for your help!

Comment: I think sessions are different for each client, session variables in client1 and client2 doesn't match.

Comment: so what you're looking for is "PHP Shared Memory": http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php

Comment: Perfect! thank you, how can i mark your comment as answer?

Comment: Nice! I've posted answer, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24043534/1262820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for is **PHP Shared Memory**:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php

In order to use this feature,  the shmop support must be enabled (usually it's already enabled).

USAGE - See code below:

```
<?php

//feature detection
if (function_exists('shmop_open'))
{

    $sys_id = 888;
    $access_mode = 'c';
    $perm = 0755; #shared memory segment perm; Permissions: a|w|c|m
    $size = 512; #size in bytes

    $shm_id = shmop_open($sys_id, $access_mode, $perm, $size); #Create segment

    //write into shared memory segment
    $bytes_written = shmop_write($shm_id, 'PHP SHARED MEMORY', 0);

    echo $bytes_written;

} else {
    echo 'Shared Memory support is not ennabled.';
}
```

For further info read the docs: [PHP Shared Memory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php)